# Why is Google Geofencing API on Android not working on all devices

Tags: android, google-api, location, google-play-services, android-geofence

I have been using the Google Geofencing Service on Android for quite some time now and I just found out that the geofence transitions are not triggered on all devices. I've always tested with my HTC Nexus 5 and HTC Desire 320. But now I can see that the same code does not work on an Asus Zenfone 2 nor a Samsung Galaxy Tab 4.

Has someone successfully tested the Google Geofencing Api on a device that is not from HTC? Even the [sample project](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/Geofencing) is not working on these devices...

Note: I will not post my code, it is the same as the [example from the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html).

Answer (score 0):

Google geofence relies HEAVILY on network locations, which can have some outrageous accuracies at time (4km+ for Nexus 5).  If the accuracy is bigger than your geofence radius, don't expect an enter event (nor exit if you don't that initial enter event).

I would double check the location settings (Power Save mode is bad for geofencing), and also make sure that you are not in an environment that degrades GPS (Google silently takes GPS points for geofences, FYI).

As for the devices I've tested on:

- Galaxy S4 & S5
- Motorola Moto G (2nd Gen) & Droid Maxxx
- Nexus 5 & 6

Works on all of them (but not always well).